# Сортировка строк

Tags: c, массивы

Вообщем дана строка в файле, задача напечатать все слова, которые встречаются в последовательности по одному разу.

У меня сейчас удаляет повторно входящие слова, то есть если в файле это содержимое

> qwert,qw,qwert,qaz,qwert,qaz,qwe.

Она выдает

> qwert,qw,qaz,qwe.

Это не то, мне нужно, чтобы выдало

> qw,qwe.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *f1, *f2;                //2 файла
    char nameIn[20];                //имя файла1(длина)
    char nameOut[20];                //имя файла2(длина)
    char source[256];
    char dest[256] = { '\0' };
    char *buf;
    char *s;
    int size;
    printf("Vvedite imy faila: ");        //спрашиваешь имя
    scanf("%s", nameIn);        //считываешь имя
    f1 = fopen(nameIn, "r");        //открываем файл 1
    while (f1 == NULL)                //цикл от ошибок,если не сущевствует файла1
    {
        printf("tError!n");
        printf("Vvedite imy faila: ");        //спрашиваешь имя
        scanf("%s", nameIn);        //считываешь имя
        f1 = fopen(nameIn, "r");        //открытие файла1
    }
    size = filelength(fileno(f1));        //получаем размер файла
    int readsize = fread(source, sizeof(char), sizeof(char) * size, f1);        //читают строку из файла по символам.в переменную readsize записывается размер
    buf = strtok(source, ",.");
    while (buf != '\0') {
        s = strstr(dest, buf);        //Функция strstr() возвращает указатель на первое вхождение подстроки, адресуемой параметром str2, в строку, адресуемую параметром str1. Если совпадение не обнаружено, возвращается нулевой указатель.
        if (!s || *(s + strlen(buf)) != ',') {
            strcat(dest, buf);        //присоединяет к строке str1 копию строки str2
            strcat(dest, ",");        //присоединяет к строке str1 копию строки str2
        }
        buf = strtok(0, ",.");
    }
    dest[strlen(dest) - 1] = '.';
    printf("Vvedite imy vihodnogo faila: ");        //спрашиваешь имя
    scanf("%s", nameOut);        //считываешь имя
    f2 = fopen(nameOut, "w");        //открытие файла2
    printf("n");
    printf("tRezultat izmeneniy: n");
    printf("%s", dest);
    fprintf(f2, "%s", dest);
    fclose(f2);                        //закрытие файла2
    fclose(f1);                        //закрытие файла1
    getch();
}
```

Comment: В метках должен быть указан 1) язык программирования, 2) учебное задание.

Comment: @Spectre,

А конкретно по делу можешь что нибудь сказать?

Comment: когда вопрос прочитают люди, знающие C++, тогда и скажут по делу

Comment: Если правильно понял, Вам надо из слов (разделители '.' и ',') входной строки получить строку из тех слов, которые входят в исходную **ровно один раз**.

Так ?

Тогда Ваш алгоритм неправильный. 

Причем здесь сортировка и два файла не понимаю.

Comment: @wapdimon72ru,Дак я знаю что не правильный,она у меня щас просто удаляет повтрные вхождения слов,а надо чтобы показывало только те которые встречаются как вы написали ровно один раз

2 файла это потому что,строка исходная берется из файла 1 ,и результативная строка записывается в файл 2,и вывод результат на экран.Подкорректируйте мой код пожалуйста

Comment: а можно это все в коде?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Его надо не подправлять, а полностью переделывать.

Суть алгоритма. Выбираете слова из исходной строки и складываете их в промежуточную таблицу пар (слово, количество повторений). Реализаций может быть много. Для начала сделайте попроще, например массив структур. Для каждого нового слова тупо пробегаете по всем структурам и если нашли там это слово, то увеличиваете счетчик. Если не нашли, то добавляете в конец со счетчиком равным 1. Размер массива (с запасом) можно оценить, как длину входной строки, деленную на 2.

В конце формируете выход из слов с счетчиком равным 1.